# M1 Mac facing error when compiling rust code

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, apple-m1

I have started using the Mac m1, When I try to compile or build the rust code it will give me error as show below. Please any could give suggestion how I can build a rust project using m1.

`` error occurred: Failed to find tool. Is `musl-gcc` installed ``

```
Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/Users/vlas/workspace/atomicDEX-API/target/debug/build/secp256k1-sys-a8b7f720201711aa/build-script-build` (exit code: 1)
  --- stdout
  TARGET = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-musl")
  OPT_LEVEL = Some("0")
  HOST = Some("aarch64-apple-darwin")
  CC_x86_64-unknown-linux-musl = None
  CC_x86_64_unknown_linux_musl = None
  TARGET_CC = None
  CC = None
  CROSS_COMPILE = None
  CFLAGS_x86_64-unknown-linux-musl = None
  CFLAGS_x86_64_unknown_linux_musl = None
  TARGET_CFLAGS = None
  CFLAGS = None
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  DEBUG = Some("true")
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
  CC_x86_64-unknown-linux-musl = None
  CC_x86_64_unknown_linux_musl = None
  TARGET_CC = None
  CC = None
  CROSS_COMPILE = None
  CFLAGS_x86_64-unknown-linux-musl = None
  CFLAGS_x86_64_unknown_linux_musl = None
  TARGET_CFLAGS = None
  CFLAGS = None
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
  CC_x86_64-unknown-linux-musl = None
  CC_x86_64_unknown_linux_musl = None
  TARGET_CC = None
  CC = None
  CROSS_COMPILE = None
  CFLAGS_x86_64-unknown-linux-musl = None
  CFLAGS_x86_64_unknown_linux_musl = None
  TARGET_CFLAGS = None
  CFLAGS = None
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
  running: "musl-gcc" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-g" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-m64" "-I" "depend/secp256k1/" "-I" "depend/secp256k1/include" "-I" "depend/secp256k1/src" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-DSECP256K1_BUILD=1" "-DENABLE_MODULE_ECDH=1" "-DECMULT_GEN_PREC_BITS=4" "-DUSE_NUM_NONE=1" "-DUSE_FIELD_INV_BUILTIN=1" "-DUSE_SCALAR_INV_BUILTIN=1" "-DECMULT_WINDOW_SIZE=15" "-DUSE_EXTERNAL_DEFAULT_CALLBACKS=1" "-DUSE_ENDOMORPHISM=1" "-o" "/Users/vlas/workspace/atomicDEX-API/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/debug/build/secp256k1-sys-14880e4c64cda3d3/out/depend/secp256k1/contrib/lax_der_parsing.o" "-c" "depend/secp256k1/contrib/lax_der_parsing.c"

  --- stderr


  error occurred: Failed to find tool. Is `musl-gcc` installed?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are missing a Linker

```
brew install filosottile/musl-cross/musl-cross
```